# QTP does not Recognize HTA applications

Tags: qtp, hta

I have created a HTA application.I tried to record by using QTP. But QTP does not recognize that application.
Is there any patch in QTP to record HTA applications.

Comment: Post your code of this HTA !

Comment: @Hackoo,Thank you for viewing my post. Take any sample HTA application. QTP is not recognizing HTA applications.

Comment: I have a similar issue with RoyalTS not seeing HTA apps as windows, I don't know as how there is anyway around it.